# Neo4j graphDatabaseService blows up on context initialization if remote DB is down

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-graph

When the Neo4j config is initialzed, and the remote DB is not running, the server will not start ...

```
    <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" />
    <bean id="graphDatabaseService class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="http://220.10.25.24:7474/db/data/" /> 
    </bean>
```

is there a way to gracefully stop or halt it's creation when the server isn't running ?

This is a module in a much larger Application & I can't not start the app b/c Neo4j has stopped running ..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there is a good hook in there, maybe you can raise an issue in  https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding on exposing either an exception or some check method to find out if the neo4j server is alive?